# Go - middleware blocks MIME type of each requests

Tags: api, rest, curl, go, mime-types

I modiefied the middleware of [this tutorial](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware) to check for all PUT and POST request the JSON MIME type.

But the middleware seems to respond everytime with "Mediatype Not Supported". I tried the curl command below where I set explicitly the right MIME type. I print which each request the client's Content-Type header field which is allways "text/plain; charset=utf-8".

The Middleware:

```
func EnforceJSON(h httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        // Check the existence of a request body
        if req.ContentLength == 0 {
            http.Error(rw, http.StatusText(400), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        // Check the MIME type
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        buf.ReadFrom(req.Body)
        // Prints "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
        fmt.Println(http.DetectContentType(buf.Bytes()))
        if http.DetectContentType(buf.Bytes()) != "application/json; charset=utf-8" {
            http.Error(rw, http.StatusText(415), http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType)
            return
        }

        h(rw, req, ps)
    }
}  
...
router.POST("/api/v1/users", EnforceJSON(CreateUser))
```

My curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-X POST \
-d '{"JSON": "Will be checked after the middleware accepted the MIME type."}' \
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
```

Alternativly I tried [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) but the result was the same.

Comment: You stated the answer yourself, `DetectContentType` returns `text/plain`. Normally you just use the content-type that the client supplied.

Comment: Yes, I want the fype of content that the client send to me. The docs says: DetectContentType implements the algorithm described at http://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/ to determine the Content-Type of the given data. It considers at most the first 512 bytes of data. DetectContentType always returns a valid MIME type: if it cannot determine a more specific one, it returns "application/octet-stream".  Why should the function determine the wrong content type?

Comment: DetectContentType  is only guaranteed to return a *valid* type, which it does -- json data is *text/plain`. Some types are ambiguous, and sniffing couldn't reliably detect valid json limited to only 512 bytes of input.

Comment: But isn't it usual to request a restful API with "application/json"?

Comment: Yes, so why don't you read the `Content-Type` header instead of trying to guess it from the request body?

Comment: This function should solve my problem: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of DetectContentType function they follow the rules described on "MIME Sniffing" guide (https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/).

To determine the MIME Type by the content this specific function use the item *"7. Determining the computed MIME type of a resource"*. That item doesn't have a determination for *'application/json'* type and following these rules will result in a *'text/plain'* MIME type.

This is visible on the function *match* on the *DetectContentType* implementation (https://golang.org/src/net/http/sniff.go) line 252.